# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver doesn't work anymore in java. How to fix this?

Tags: java, jdbc

It worked two days ago. Now it doesn't. I'm 100% sure the coding is correct. This is the way I used to connect the database. Couldn't find an answer yet to my problem. Please give me an answer as i'm a beginner for java language. (Using jdk 7u72)

```
public void set()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String su=new String("jdbc:odbc:MOVIESURF"); //This is the database
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(su,"","");
        st=con.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e2){System.out.println(e2);}
}
```

This is the stack trace

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
         at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
         at A.set(jptest7.java:410)
         at A.actionPerformed(jptest7.java:560)
         at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
         at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
         at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
         at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Connection failed select PASSWORD from USERS where USERNAME='ashane' ERROR:
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: You can still run it with JDK 7 if it is still installed. Via this: /full/path/to/jdk7/bin/java signup. However, I would instead make an effort to find a JDBC driver and add it to your classpath so you dont see errors like this again

Comment: @cowls You are correct. I have jdk 7 and 8 installed. I'm still trying to figure out how I installed version 8 as i don't have the setup??!

Comment: Maybe some System/Application update installed it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, your system is now running on the Java 8 JRE.  The ODBC Bridge has been removed from this, and all future versions.  You need to find a native JDBC driver for the database you want to connect to, and put that on your classpath.

```
java -classpath "[/path/to/your/driver.jar];." [yourclassname]
```

Alternatively, you could explicitly use the JDK 7 runtime, but I'd recommend against this.  You've uncovered a compatibility problem, and it's better to solve it than to try to work around it.

Comment: Thank all of you for helping me around. If i'm to use a IDE, which is better to use as a step 1? net-beans or eclipse?

Comment: Sadly, that question is argumentative (and therefore off-topic for SO).  I *personally* use eclipse, but both have their pros and cons.  If you're a beginner, using the command line as you are is actually quite helpful, because it forces you to learn what the IDEs are doing for you.  You can move up to the power tools when you're comfortable with the hand tools.

Comment: I'll second what @IanMcLaird says about using the command line (but not about Eclipse as I _personally_ use NetBeans). Understanding and solving classpath problems outside of the IDE is a skill [most beginners lack](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=classpath+eclipse) even though it's a vital skill for anyone wanting to advance as a programmer. Kudos to you for working through these issues using a text editor and the command line - your understanding of Java and the JVM will put you ahead of your peers.

Answer (score -3):

Please add your jar to the class path like below.

java -cp .;C:\Program Files\MySQL\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar MysqlConnect

Note:Please replace msql connector with your jar file as per requirement.

Comment: Where can I get this connector you are saying? Can you please explain more?

Comment: You can download the connector from oracle website before that you will have to check which version of java you are using. So, depends upon Java version you can choose connector. It should be something like classes12.jar or ojdbc14.jar.

Comment: -1 - *"Do you even have specific reason?"* - Yes.  Because the answer is incorrect.  The missing class is not a JDBC driver.  And the fact that ODBC is involved means that it is highly unlikely that he was using MySQL.